# docker and container is running well, but I can't open that folder from docker inspect container |grep Source

Tags: docker, go, ubuntu, containers, ubuntu-18.04

My docker and project-server is running normally, but when I inspect location of `project-server`,

```
docker inspect project-server |grep Source

            "Source": "/home/project/project/golang/docker/project-server/...",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_project-server-data/_data",
```

and try to open that location `cd /home/project/project/golang/docker`, I got error of `-bash: cd: /home/project/project/golang/docker/: No such file or directory`

when I type `ls` on folder of `/home/project/project/`,I get only github folder, there is no folder named `golang`,

```
  github
```

Is there anybody who know why the folder is not existed, but all server is working well?

Comment: you can run ```docker inspect project-server```  and see “Mounts”, It will show you where the path to mount is. if you mount a dir(not file),  it will be a random path like "/var/lib/docker/volumes/96256232eb74edb139d652746f0fe426e57fbacdf73376963e3acdb411b3d73a/_data"

Comment: @Para Hi, thanks, It's a file, and the path to mount path is also `/home/project/golang/docker/project-server/...`. it's same as `docker inspect project-server |grep Source`

Comment: @null username directory is missing in the path `/home/{username}/` which may contain your project folder

Comment: @Chandan project is `username`, as I said, every container is running normally, but I can't open that folder, I am `root` user

Comment: @null please attach the `Dockerfile` in question